# example of a simple Galois extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I would like to find a simple Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha )/\mathbb{Q}$ whose order is odd and has at laest two different prime divisors (i.e. $|Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})|=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha ):\mathbb{Q}]$ is odd and it is not of the form $p^k$ for some $p\in \mathbb{P},k \in \mathbb{N} $) such that:

$Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}) \neq \bigcup_{\mathbb{Q}\subsetneq M\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)} Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/M)$

That is, there is an automorphism $\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})$ and a sub field $\mathbb{Q}\subsetneq M\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that $\sigma|_M\neq id$.

---

Somehow it seems to me like the answer should be obvious but I cant see it,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find an $\alpha$ that generates $\Bbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/7),\cos(2\pi/11))$. The Galois group is cyclic of order $15$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - could you explain why does in your example $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}) \neq \bigcup_{\mathbb{Q}\subsetneq M\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)} Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/M)$ ?

Comment: The non-trivial proper subgroups have orders $5,3$ respectively. Their union...?

Comment: Oh, of course! thanks a lot.

Comment: Great that you see the light1 For more feedback feel free to post an answer with the details.